# In Illustrator CS6, why can't I use the variable width selection?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

It looks like this to me:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/fbXDkfw.png]

Where the second box is the variable width option. If it helps I expanded my path.

Comment: You have not provided enough information. Is the width profile always blank? If you draw a standard path does it appear? If yes to either of these, provide details about the selected path with the profile disappears.

Comment: You can only use variable width on a stroke. As you said, you've expanded so you no longer have the stroke you need to use this option. Is it still happening if you haven't yet expanded?

Answer (score 2):

No stroke, no variable width profile for that stroke.
It appears your selection has no stroke- which if this is the case you wouldn't have a width profile.
Unless I'm misunderstanding this, you have to add a stroke.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Adams suggestion, that you have no settings applied to the selection, it could also be caused by the selected paths having different settings, therefore it won't show any settings except the ones that are the same for all selected paths.

But you can then choose a setting that will be applied to all selected paths **and then** the settings will appear - because all selected paths have the same settings.